# Call a function in the main window when closing another popup window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, window

I have a page. When you click on a link in that page it opens a popup window. When you click on a link in the popup window it opens a new popup window and closes the first popup. In this last popup you can edit some information. When this window closes I need to call a function in the first page.

I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        window.opener.opener.relcontacten();
    }
</script>
```

Where `relcontacten()` is a function defined in the first page and looks like this:

```
function relcontacten(){
    $.get(
        'contactlijst.php',
        function(response){
            $('#ContactLijst').html(response);
        }
    );
}
```

Does anyone know a way to call a function in a specific window without using opener?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with **localStorage**.

you can write data to it by doing

```
localStorage.setItem('move_to_step_two', 'true');
```

and putting an event listener on it to listen in each window if we moved a step (window 1 will close itself in case **move_to_step_two** became true).

you can sync between several windows from the same site this way

Answer (score 0):

try to use .load()

```
function relcontacten(){
     $('#ContactLijst').load('contactlijst.php');
}
```

and beforeunload you can use

```
 window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        relcontacten();
 });
```